# Inferring type of TypeScript lookup value

Tags: typescript, lookup, typescript-generics

I was expecting the example below to work but it seems that TypeScript cannot reduce the type of my lookup argument based on the value of another argument. Am I missing a trick or am I asking too much of the type system?

```js
interface Actions {
  CHANGE_NAME: string;
  DONT_CHANGE_NAME: void;
}

const state = { name: 'Example' };

const reduce = <K extends keyof Actions>(type: K, payload: Actions[K]): void => {
    if (type === 'CHANGE_NAME') state.name = payload;
                                   //  error here
};
```

Produces the following error

```
Type 'Actions[K]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'string | void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

If I add a manual type assertion then it will work but I thought this was the purpose of `Actions[K]`. What am I misunderstanding?

```js
// Works, but I'm trying to avoid this...
if (type === 'CHANGE_NAME') state.name = payload as Actions["CHANGE_NAME"];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iAzsgbwChlkBhACVQDkBxAUQH1rUBZegLmVzClAHMA3CWQARAPLUAKo0o0GzNp2QA3LMAAmwgL5EiCHD25g4kZAF5CyEHAC2ELgHJ6ADzsAHADYRHybcP1DMGQoCA0AVyQLZAAeAGlkCBdIEA18AGsIAE8sGDQMbDwAPgAKMCz3B2Q4gBpkdzgszyw4DS50TEMAbTiAXQBKLjVNCyLCEVJgPLKKlHN55Ec5OiYWdkd%2041MIADobe2iGppatIn8gA)

Comment: This is Microsoft/TypeScript#13995, I think

Comment: @jcalz OK that's a shame but I agree, it looks like the same problem. Thanks for the quick reply.